# How to compare two columns in Excel and copy the corresponding value in the next column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 3 columns in my Excel list. Column A contains "computer names", column C contains "Computer names" and column D contains "IP addresses". I want to compare data in column A with column C and if a match is found, copy the corresponding value in column D (IP Address) into column B.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: It's a **column** - not a *coloumn* (just a tiny - but consistent - spelling mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP`

Example in cell `B1`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C1:D4,2, FALSE)
```

where `C1:D4` is the table that contains computer names and their corresponding IP addresses.